# Do monads and comonads with the same functor always compose?

Tags: category-theory, monads

Given a functor $F$, a monad $M=(F, \mu,\eta)$ and a comonad $N=(F,\delta, \xi)$, do $M, N$ always compose to form a bimonad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Take for example any pointed category $\mathcal{C}$, and let $1$ denote the category with exactly one morphism. There is a unique functor $\mathcal{C}\to 1$, and the functor $1\to \mathcal{C}$ that just picks the zero object is both its left and right adjoint. So composing the two gives an endofunctor of $\mathcal{C}$ that just maps every object to the zero object of $\mathcal{C}$, and this functor has a monad and a comonad structure.

However they cannot form a bimonad structure in the sense of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.1163). Indeed one of the conditions there is that the composition of the unit and counit is the identity transformation of the identity endofunctor on $\mathcal{C}$; but here the unit is $X\to 0$ and the counit is $0\to X$, so their composition is the zero transformation and not the identity.